# How to debug gulpfile.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, debugging, gulp, node-inspector

What is the proper way to execute `node-inspector` in order to be able to debug `gulpfile.js`?

I've tried following (code in my gulpfile requires `harmony` and `harmony-arrow-functions switches`):

```sh
node-debug --nodejs --harmony --nodejs --harmony-arrow-functions /home/user/.npm-packages/bin/gulp default
```

Node inspector was properly loaded however it was not possible to set breakpoint in gulpfile neither before nor after the file was [loaded](https://github.com/gulpjs/gulp/blob/master/bin/gulp.js#L116). It was also not possible to set breakpoints in `gulp/index.js` and `orchestrator/index.js` files. And it was not possible to "step into" following statement ([whole source](https://github.com/gulpjs/gulp/blob/master/bin/gulp.js#L129)):

```javascript
gulpInst.start.apply(gulpInst, toRun);
```

Environment:

- Fedora 21 x64
- Node Inspector v0.9.2
- node v0.12.0
- gulp

  - CLI version 3.8.11
  - Local version 3.8.11

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It looks like you're missing pointing to your actual gulpfile.js. Try something like this:

```
node-debug /path/to/your/gulp/install/gulp.js --harmony --harmony-arrow-functions --gulpfile /path/to/your/gulpfile/gulpfile.js default
```

I use this and it works.