# How to debug app startup with Gulp

Tags: node.js, gulp, node-inspector, gulp-node-inspector

I have run into a road block with a new team I am working with that supports a node app.  The app is launched via Gulp, and the setup is such that there is a "core" NPM module that defines a bunch of gulp tasks and a "server", and our app simply installs this package and our code is copied in as a "plugin" to the server.

In our gulpfile.js, we have something like:

```
var gulp = require('gulp');
var workflow = require('base-workflow');

workflow.use({ gulp: gulp });
gulp.task('default'), ['base:default']);
...more stuff
```

Where `base:default` is pulled in and a couple of Hapi servers are ultimately started (one as a "web" app, one as the "rest" proxy app to a real Java-based REST services).  What I would like to do is setup node-inpector so that I can troubleshoot the startup of the app because I have found that the latest versions of their base packages are not Mac-compatible.

What I have tried is to install [gulp-node-inspector](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-node-inspector) with the following changes:

```
var gulp = require('gulp');
var nodeInspector = require('gulp-node-inspector');
var workflow = require('base-workflow');

workflow.use({ gulp: gulp });
gulp.task('default'), ['base:default']);
gulp.task('debug', ['default'], function() { gulp.src([]).pipe(nodeInspector({debugBrk: true})); });
...more stuff
```

and also:

```
var gulp = require('gulp');
var nodeInspector = require('gulp-node-inspector');
var workflow = require('base-workflow');

workflow.use({ gulp: gulp });
gulp.task('default'), ['base:default']);
gulp.task('debug', function() { gulp.src(['default']).pipe(nodeInspector({debugBrk: true})); });
...more stuff
```

but neither of those works.  Part of this is most likely my lack of understanding of Gulp.  Does anyone know how I can debug this app?

Answer (score 0):

I spent a fair bit of time googling and trying the various solutions out there; in the end the one that worked for me was the accepted answer found on this page:

[How to debug gulpfile.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29201843/how-to-debug-gulpfile-js)

This was the only one that allowed me to actually hit my "debugger" command in my gulp task.

I should also note that I had to completely uninstall and reinstall "node-inspector"; there was a version problem and when I was on the verge of solving it I was getting some "cannot find module" error because the version of node-inspector was causing it to point to the wrong folder.  Once I uninstalled and reinstalled (via npm) then it worked.  In my case I'm on a Windows machine and the command that worked looked like the following:

node-debug C:\myPathWhereGulpfileDotJsExists\node_modules\gulp\bin\gulp.js --gulpfile C:\myPathWhereGulpfileDotJsExists\gulpfile.js myTestTaskContainingDebuggerCommand

Answer (score 0):

Maby this solution help you

```
node --inspect --debug-brk ./node_modules/gulp fonts
```

Answer (score 0):

The best way to do this now is to add a `debugger;` to the place in the file you would like to add a breakpoint to, or set it manually once the debugger has started with `setBreakpoint('gulpFile.js', 1)`

Then simply

```
node inspect --inspect-brk $(which gulp) taskName
c
```

More information about debugging with node [here](https://nodejs.org/api/debugger.html)